# Is there a command line option for setting the default log level in Java

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

Can I do something along the lines of:

```
-Djava.util.logging.loglevel=FINE
```

Obviously that doesn't work, but you get the idea.  Is there anything like that?  Or am I forced to create a properties file?

Comment: Yes and it is documented. See `java.util.logging`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can even pass your log Level as a user defined property.

```
-DmyProp.logLevel=FINE
```

In your code:

```
String logLevel = System.getProperties("myProp.logLevel");
```

But I have the idea that your are looking for a more "built-in" and automatically handled property, right? AFAIK, it doesn't exist, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: yeah, i was hoping for something more built-in, but maybe this is the best i can do

Comment: if you replaced `"myProp.logLevel"` by `"java.util.logging.loglevel"` in the call to `getProperties(..)`, it would work like guessed in the question. (except that you would have to parse the loglevel yourself ?)

Comment: this answer does not explain how to actually use the value obtained from the system property to change logging levels.

Answer (score 5):

### tldr:

for java-9+ put this code at the beginning of your `main` method:
(see the bottom for java-8 and earlier)

```java
final var cmdLineVal = System.getProperty("java.util.logging.loglevel");
if (cmdLineVal != null) {
    LogManager.getLogManager().updateConfiguration(
        (key) -> (oldVal, newVal) ->
            key.equals(".level") || key.equals("java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level")
            ? cmdLineVal : newVal
    );
}
```

### explanation and workaround if `main` cannot be modified:

Generally `java.util.logging` does not use system properties to configure itself (there are a few exceptions, like `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format`). Instead, the global [LogManager](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) singleton instance is responsible for configuring the logging subsystem and by default it loads properties from `${JAVA_HOME}/conf/logging.properties`. There are a few ways to tweak this behavior:

- provide `java.util.logging.config.file` system property with a path to an alternative logging config properties file.
- provide `java.util.logging.config.class` system property with a class name that completely overrides configuration process (usually by providing a custom `InputStream` with logging config properties to [readConfiguration(is)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#readConfiguration(java.io.InputStream))).
- use [LogManager.updateConfiguration(mapper)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#updateConfiguration(java.util.function.Function)) method (**java 9+**) to override selected properties only. Note that this method can only override existing properties, but cannot add new ones (for that, a way more cumbersome [updateConfiguration(inputStream, mapper)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#updateConfiguration(java.io.InputStream,java.util.function.Function)) would need to be used).

So in case of overriding the global root log-level, it's probably easiest to use `updateConfiguration(mapper)` somewhere at the beginning of your `main` method. `LogManager` uses `.level` property (level of the empty-string root logger) as a default for its child loggers not configured explicitly, so using the `java.util.logging.loglevel` system property from the OP, it would be like this:

```java
final var cmdLineVal = System.getProperty("java.util.logging.loglevel");
if (cmdLineVal != null) {
    LogManager.getLogManager().updateConfiguration(
        (key) -> (oldVal, newVal) ->
            key.equals(".level")
            ? cmdLineVal : newVal
    );
}
```

Note that in case of the default logging config, the above is not sufficient for any `FINE` (or lower) log entries to be output on the console, as [ConsoleHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/ConsoleHandler.html) by default outputs `INFO` and higher. To change this, you need to override also `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level` logging config property. If you want to use the same system property for this again, then you need to modify the argument of `updateConfiguration` like the below:

```java
final var cmdLineVal = System.getProperty("java.util.logging.loglevel");
if (cmdLineVal != null) {
    LogManager.getLogManager().updateConfiguration(
        (key) -> (oldVal, newVal) ->
            key.equals(".level")
                || key.equals("java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level")
            ? cmdLineVal : newVal
    );
}
```

If you can't change the `main` method, then you can define the previously mentioned `java.util.logging.config.class` property to point to your class like this: `-Djava.util.logging.config.class=com.example.MyJulConfigurator`. This will delegate the task of logging configuration to the constructor of this class. In such constructor you can first read the config from a file the normal way (using [readConfiguration()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#readConfiguration()) method) and then use the code from the previous snippet:

```java
public MyJulConfigurator() throws IOException {
    System.clearProperty("java.util.logging.config.class");
    LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration();

    // the same code as in the previous snippet:
    final var cmdLineVal = System.getProperty("java.util.logging.loglevel");
    if (cmdLineVal != null) {
        LogManager.getLogManager().updateConfiguration(
            (key) -> (oldVal, newVal) ->
                key.equals(".level") || key.equals("java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level")
                ? cmdLineVal : newVal
        );
    }
}
```

As a final note, I've recently written a simple helper function to make any ad-hoc command-line changes to logging config easier: [overrideLogLevelsWithSystemProperties](https://github.com/morgwai/jul-utils/blob/v4.0/src/main/java/pl/morgwai/base/jul/JulConfigurator.java#L33-L70) (also supports adding new logging properties).
As mentioned by @TWiStErRob in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160471/is-there-a-command-line-option-for-setting-the-default-log-level-in-java/67930414#comment122392302_67930414), you don't even need to include the containing `jul-utils` as a dependency of your project: just add it to your classpath (available in [central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/pl.morgwai.base/jul-utils/)) when starting your app and define your desired system properties:

```bash
java -cp /path/to/jul-utils.jar:${CLASSPATH} \
-Djava.util.logging.config.class=pl.morgwai.base.jul.JulConfigurator \
-Djava.util.logging.overrideLevel=,java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler,com.third.party.talkative.lib \
-D.level=FINE \
-Djava.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINE \
-Dcom.third.party.talkative.lib.level=SEVERE \
${MY_JAVA_APP_MAINCLASS_AND_ARGUMENTS}
```

### outline for java-8 and earlier:

1. parse the config file manually into a `Properties` using [load(is)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)) (see [here](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.logging/share/classes/java/util/logging/LogManager.java#L1382) how `LogManager` determines which file to read)
2. replace values for `.level` and `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level` using [setProperty(key, value)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) with the value obtained from the system property
3. store the updated properties into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` using [store(os, null)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html#store(java.io.Writer,java.lang.String))
4. wrap [the underlying data](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray()) with a `ByteArrayInputStream` (see also [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778658/how-do-i-convert-an-outputstream-to-an-inputstream)) and pass it to [readConfiguration(is)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#readConfiguration(java.io.InputStream))

as before, you can do it either in your `main` method or in a constructor of some class pointed by `java.util.logging.config.class` system property.

Comment: The code you provided along with the `java.util.logging.config.class` property is pretty good. The class set in the property can be part of the project OR it could be just appended to the classpath as an extra JAR file, adding functionality to any JVM execution. Still I think `java.util.logging.config.file` is the best configuration option. Future readers: take a look at the default properties file, it's well-documented in the file itself.

Comment: @TWiStErRob `java.util.logging.config.file` is best as a permanent solution for sure. `updateLogLevels` is meant for quick temporary changes when starting program manually from a command line (for example when debugging etc), which is exactly what OP was looking for.

Comment: @TWiStErRob I didn't even think about non-dependency, runtime-only usage of it: I guess it's a good selling point :)  Thanks for pointing this!

Comment: +1 for the tidbit about `SimpleFormatter.format` being the exception about being usable in command line! That was what got me here... Seeing that working I assumed anything that can be put into the properties file could also be passed as a system property (through the command line). A bad assumption it seems! :)

Answer (score 2):

you can  configure your code to set  the level based on an envrioment variable :

```
String sLoglevel= System.getenv("LOGLEVEL");  
int ilevel = loglevel.parseInt(sLoglevel);
//set the log level based on retrieved value
```