# Override log level (java.util.logging) with JVM-argument?

Tags: java, logging, jvm-arguments, java.util.logging

Is it possible to override/set log level of java.util.logging.Logger by passing an JVM option on start of the application?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470430/java-util-logging-logger-doesnt-respect-java-util-logging-level. You can get a clue from that.

Comment: this may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160471/is-there-a-command-line-option-for-setting-the-default-log-level-in-java/67930414#67930414

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a command line option for setting the default log level in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160471/is-there-a-command-line-option-for-setting-the-default-log-level-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are the following system properties available where you can configure log levels of loggers and initialisation logic.

- java.util.logging.manager

  - You can define your own LogManager
- java.util.logging.config.class

  - Custom logging configuration as a Class file
- java.util.logging.config.file

  - Custom logging configuration as configuration file

The LogManager documentation has more information on them available, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html

Comment: Thanks, you verified what I believed as well.