# How to set java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level from command line arguments?

Tags: java, logging, command-line, java.util.logging

Current default global logging level is set to **INFO** in *JRE_HOME/lib/logging.properties* file.

I run the following from the command line to over-ride and set the level to FINE:

```
mvn test -Dtest=ABC -Djava.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINE
```

And, I use the below in my code:

```
logger.fine("Logging works for fine");
```

The above message doesn't get printed in the output.

If I change it to the below line, it prints successfully.

```
logger.info("Logging works for fine");
```

What am I missing?

Comment: clearly you are not over riding the logging at the command-line and it's behaving as if it's set to INFO, which you said is the default.

Comment: Yes. I am not able to over-ride which I thought would happen. Any clue why?

Comment: Why did you think you were overriding? Where did you see that being done / documented?

Comment: To change logging options from command-line, tell Java to load a *different* logging configuration file, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/960133/5221149).

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160471/is-there-a-command-line-option-for-setting-the-default-log-level-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command switch `-Djava.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINE` just adds a [system property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties--) entry.  This is not used or read by the logging API.

Instead, all of the logging properties are managed by the [LogManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html).
Here is a self contained program to show how you the `LogManager` can change settings:

```
public class LogManagerTest {

    public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException {
        read(LogManager.getLogManager(), create());
        Handler h = new ConsoleHandler();
        System.out.println(h.getLevel());
        h.close();
    }

    private static Properties create() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level", 
                "FINE");
        return props;
    }

    private static void read(LogManager manager, Properties props) throws IOException {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(512);
        props.store(out, "No comment");
        manager.readConfiguration(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
    }
}
```

Like @Andreas pointed out, you are going to create a new properties file with the adjusted parameters and [set the system property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960099/how-to-set-up-java-logging-using-a-properties-file-java-util-logging/960133#960133) to have the `LogManager` use the new properties file with your desired settings.

Answer (score 2):

To add to [the answer by jmehrens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49416230/1220560): if you are using **java-9** or later, then a much easier way to override `LogManager`'s property, is to use [LogManager.updateConfiguration(mapper)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#updateConfiguration(java.util.function.Function)) method.
So in the case of `ConsoleHandler`'s level:

```java
final var propertyName = "java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level";
var cmdLineVal = System.getProperty(propertyName);
if (cmdLineVal != null) {
    LogManager.getLogManager().updateConfiguration(
            (key) -> (oldVal, newVal) ->
                    key.equals(propertyName) ? cmdLineVal : newVal);
}
```

Note, that you cannot use `updateConfiguration(...)` to add new properties: only modify the existing ones.

**update:** I've just written a simple function to make ad-hoc command-line changes to logging config easier: [overrideLogLevelsWithSystemProperties](https://github.com/morgwai/jul-utils/blob/v2.1/src/main/java/pl/morgwai/base/jul/JulConfigurator.java#L23-L61) (also supports adding new logging properties).
you don't even need to include the containing `jul-utils` as a dependency of your project: just add it to your classpath (available in [central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/pl.morgwai.base/jul-utils/)) when starting your app and define your desired system properties:

```bash
java -cp /path/to/jul-utils.jar:${CLASSPATH} \
-Djava.util.logging.config.class=pl.morgwai.base.jul.JulConfigurator \
-Djava.util.logging.overrideLevel=,java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler,com.third.party.talkative.lib \
-D.level=FINE \
-Djava.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINE \
-Dcom.third.party.talkative.lib.level=SEVERE \
${MY_JAVA_APP_MAINCLASS_AND_ARGUMENTS}
```